# What does the bold part mean??(unity error log)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

UnityEngine.Graphics.Internal_SetRTSimple (UnityEngine.RenderBuffer color, UnityEngine.RenderBuffer depth, System.Int32 mip, UnityEngine.CubemapFace face, System.Int32 depthSlice) **(at <127e81e1cb3441cc97d26b1910daae77>:0)**

I wonder what that part means

Comment: Generated class name and line number?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `(at <127e81e1cb3441cc97d26b1910daae77>:0)` part of the message represents the location of the method call in the Unity3D source code.

The string `127e81e1cb3441cc97d26b1910daae77` is a hash that uniquely identifies the source file where the method is called, and the `:0` denotes the line number within that file.

Since it refers to Unity's internal source code, which is not publicly available, you only get auto-generated location addresses.